# Nexus3 stuck on initializing and not properly resolving content-type

Tags: docker, nginx, nexus, nginx-config

I am running `Nexus3` in a docker container on a server that also uses `nginx reverse-proxy`. The problem is that when try to access to nexus repository from a browser, I  am getting a broken page that has many console errors. Here's what I see: [image: console errors]

After looking at the network tab, I noticed that my server is not setting the proper `content-type` for my requests. This is an example of a request to a `js` file: [image: js file request]

Does anyone know what this could be? This is what my `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/confidential.com/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/confidential.com/*.confidential.com.key;
        server_name confidential.com;

    location /test {
      proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }



    }
```

Comment: I think you're headed down the wrong path in your diagnosis.  First thing to do is to make sure nginx has been configured to send in the headers Nexus Repo needs. Examples can be found here:  https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: @rseddon Thanks for the reply, but I already did what was on that page and it doesn't work.

Comment: nicely asked question, with screenshot of how "Loading Spinner Initializing..." looks. Vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
location /test {
      proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
```

The context path of Nexus needs to match the context path served through the reverse proxy.  Edit $workdir/etc/nexus.properties and set "nexus-context-path=/test".  And change the proxy_pass to be "proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/test".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Clear chrome browser cache
- Hit the url in debug mode (http://nexus:8081/?debug=true) in another browser.